# How to structure a function that uses functions from other packages in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, user-defined-functions

I created a python file with many user defined functions that I am hoping to share with other users.  However, the user defined functions themselves use a lot of functions from numpy and pandas, such as `numpy.log()` and what not.

Within those functions, I call `np.log()`, but how do I make it so that someone can use my functions, without needing to `import numpy as np`, and they could `import numpy as nump` or `import numpy` or whatever they want?

I've looked into structuring my python file as a package, but tutorials online just tell me to put each class as a different file.  Not sure if each function needs to be a different file too?  Also, I am still not sure how to solve my first issue of calling functions from another package.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to import the libraries in your functions.
If you are thinking on share this like a module/library, you have to set this on install_requires (check [this](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/)).